# Creating a simple template for a website being hosted via Apache

Tags: php, python, html, apache, templates

I am creating a website for a client. Most pages are static other than a simple contact form. It is being hosted on a Fedora server running Apache.

All pages have the same header and footer. I want to use some sort of templating for maintainability. What do you recommend for me to use and why? Also, some quick examples would not hurt.

I am mainly a Python developer (Django) but I do have experience in PHP. I'm assuming PHP would be the way to go since it is pretty easy to get up and going on Apache.

My criteria:

1. Very lightweight
2. Easy to install (either via `yum` or a quick download)
3. Pretty URLs (i.e., no `index.php?page=about`)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Server Side Includes are about as basic as you can get and are perfect for a mostly static site:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/ssi.html

That link will show you how to config the server for it and then you'd use a syntax such as:

```
<!--#include virtual="/footer.html" -->
```

If the server is running PHP, you can also use PHP includes:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: I was not aware of this! Awesome. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am also a python person and if that is an option, I would recommend [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/). It's a lot lighter weight than django and has URL routing and templating.

For templating, [mustache](http://mustache.github.com/) is very cool and has support for many different languages, including PHP as well as javascript.

Comment: Two great options! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you say that you are looking for templates, are you talking about something like smarty? Wikipedia has a good article about it http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_engine_%28web%29

Answer (score 0):

Well, the simplest way I can think of is codeigniter. It will also help you with your contact form. Follow this http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/codeigniter-from-scratch-day-4-newsletter-signup/ and check out some of the other tuts in the series. A simple mod rewrite will take care of the urls for you. Hope this helps.